# php relative path needed till project name

Tags: php

I am trying to get relative path of my project, but not exactly as required.

I have a directory structure like : `'/opt/www/myproj/folder1/folder2/myfile.php'`

So in myfile.php I am trying to get path till my project ie., `/opt/www/myproj`

I have tried differnt ways like using `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, `dirname(__FILE__)`, `basename(__FILE__)` etc..  but still no luck.

When I used `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, iam getting path till `/opt/www/`

Could anyone please tell me how can I achieve above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabio! :)